# Best Way to Handle SFTP Files in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, sftp, azure-data-factory

I'm very new to Azure in general, particularly Data Factory v2, i'm also very new at this company.  We have an ask from a vendor to query data out to a file and then drop it to an Amazon S3 bucket, however Azure Data Factory does not appear to support this.  The client wants to use an SFTP method, but i'm wondering which is the best option.  Apparently we have a Linux server all set-up but i'm not sure if it's within a VM in the cloud. I'm learning about logic apps and functions but not sure which is best way to go.  I'm familiar with WinSCP and have scripted a way to handle SFTP files in the past, but wondering if that's truly a good way to handle this.

As I said, i'm very new to this so wanting to get some ideas.  Have any of you done this in the past and what would you recommend?

I've done A ton of reading about transferring files to Amazon S3 and SFTP server.  My head is spinning.  I realize my question is general, but my team is very new and we took over this environment from a consulting firm so we don't have a lot of background.

The outcome which i'm hoping for with this post is the best, least intensive method for sending files via SFTP in Azure Data Factory

Comment: This is not a code-related question.

Comment: But data factory supports both SFTP and Amazon S3. What is not supported?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-amazon-simple-storage-service

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sftp